# Cannot post to PHP using jQuery Ajax POST method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to a PHP file using jQuery Ajax POST method but the PHP file doesn't seem to get the data from Ajax.

```
if (y == 5) {
  window.location = "../flashcard/indexFlashcard.php";
  $.post("indexSatzeargenzung.php", data:{p: punkt});
}
```

This is the way I'm trying to post the data and the PHP code that normally should get the data is:

```
$punkt = $_POST["p"]; echo $punkt;
```

It displays this notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: p in xxx\xxx\indexSatzeargenzung.php on line 2

I'm really stuck here.

Comment: try like this $.post("indexSatzeargenzung.php", data:{p: punkt));

Comment: Still, isn't working. That's really weird because because I have used post method like this in other projects and it worked as it normally should!

Comment: var_dump your $_POST and see what you've got

Comment: @ShNdrukaj Your javascript code would work perfectly if `punkt` is defined. Do you directly process data after request? Maybe you have some redirects?

Comment: As far in your code there is no problem. Can you provide more code.

Comment: Remove the line  window.location = "../flashcard/indexFlashcard.php";  Because its redirecting to that url before posting the value

Comment: just updated the provided code, punkt is defined but does the window.location above affects?

Comment: @ShNdrukaj will redirect you from page. Do it in callback

Comment: @ShNdrukaj what you want to do? want to post value and redirect to that page OR you want to post value without refreshing the page

Comment: I want to post value and then redirect to page

Comment: @ShNdrukaj My answer do it

Comment: Thank you @PavloZhukov, it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post( "indexSatzeargenzung.php", {p: punkt})
    .done(function( data ) {
        window.location = "../flashcard/indexFlashcard.php";
    });
```

Comment: It will give the same error because you are not posting p to indexFlashcard.php

Comment: @AmanRawat he meet with error in xxx\xxx\indexSatzeargenzung.php on line 2

Comment: My bad, got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery Library.
[jQuery post() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

Comment: $.post and jQuery post are same

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ajax instead of .post method:

```
if (y == 5) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"indexSatzeargenzung.php", 
        data: "p=" + punkt,
        complete: function() {
            window.location = "../flashcard/indexFlashcard.php";
        }
    });
}
```